# PFPush handlePush crash: NSCFDictionary length

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm getting a crash when the app is open and it receives a push notification.

```
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
```

the JSON is a simple alert: title, body and one custom field that's a hex number.

userInfo:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "Test Body";
            title = "Test Title";
        };
    };
    url = "miner://item/5528c5aeaacfce1fd2d527dd";
}
```

Comment: Log the dictionary and post the full result here.  Are you sure you have a valid dictionary with non-nil values?

Comment: Well a dictionary wouldn't allow nil values but posting what I do have.

Comment: Sorry, meant a non-nil dictionary.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your sample code and you're right: this kind of string messages are crashing while handled by PFPush handlePush:

The reason why this is happening:
The Parse supports iOS and Android PushNotification services at the same time, which means it cannot use any service-specific format in the general JSON string.

iOS uses these kind of formats:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

And Android

```
"data": {
            "title": "Push Title",
            "message": "Push message for Android",
            "customData": "Custom data for Android"
        }
```

In Parse, you need to use a different format type like

```
{
  "alert": "Tune in for the World Series, tonight at 8pm EDT",
  "sound": "chime",
  "title": "Baseball News"
}
```

In an iOS app, this will be the userInfo object from the JSON string above:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Tune in for the World Series, tonight at 8pm EDT";
        sound = chime;
    };
    title = "Baseball News";
}
```

In this userInfo, the alert is an NSString instead of an NSDictionary. When the Parse SDK tries to process that, it sends a length message to the instance - which causes the crash.

Sources:
https://www.parse.com/questions/json-format-to-send-notification-from-parse
https://parse.com/questions/json-push-notification-format-for-web-console-for-android-and-ios

More example:
https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#push-notifications-sending-pushes

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I wrote the following code to determine if the `alert` object is a dictionary, and if so, re-build the `userInfo` dictionary using the `body` of the `alert` dictionary as a simple string alert.

```
NSDictionary *apsDict=userInfo[@"aps"];
if (apsDict != nil) {
    id alert=apsDict[@"alert"];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableUserInfo =(NSMutableDictionary *)userInfo;
    if (alert !=nil) {
        if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            mutableUserInfo=[userInfo mutableCopy];
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableApsDict=[apsDict mutableCopy];
                mutableUserInfo[@"aps"]=mutableApsDict;
                mutableApsDict[@"alert"]=alert[@"body"];
            }
            [PFPush handlePush:mutableUserInfo];
        }
    }
}
```