# What kind of JSON data should i use swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

i'm trying to receive JSON push from website. But i have some problem.

Here is my push :

```
> $this->parsepush->send( array( "channels" => ['test'], "data" => > $post_data ));
```

Code :

> ```
> func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
>           //  PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
>    // PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
>     //batas
> ```

```
    if let msg = userInfo["aps"] as? NSObject {
        print(msg)
        print("a")
    }
    if let msg = userInfo["test"] as? NSObject {
        print(msg)
    }
    if let msg = userInfo[""] as? NSObject {
        print(msg)
    }
```

here is the print out :

```
{
}
a
```

Can only detect "aps" but without value

However my userInfo get a value like this :

```
> Printing description of userInfo:
    ▿ 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : message
        - .1 : 1235
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : aps
        - .1 : 0 elements
      ▿ [2] : 2 elements
        - .0 : link
        - .1 :
```

And then i read this [PFPush handlePush crash: NSCFDictionary length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443347/pfpush-handlepush-crash-nscfdictionary-length)
That Parse supports iOS and Android PushNotification services at the same time, which means it cannot use any service-specific format in the general JSON string.

iOS uses these kind of formats:

```
 > {
        "aps" : {
            "alert" : {
                "title" : "Game Request",
                "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
                "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
            },
            "badge" : 5,
        },
        "acme1" : "bar",
        "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
    }
```

Do i have to follow this iOS format, or i can still use my own JSON type ?

Sorry if there anything missing when explain this error.

**FIXED**

My code error because of my JSON. There's no value with a test key, only message, aps and link.

So my code be like :

```
> if let msg = userInfo["message"] as? String {
    print(msg)
}
```

Yeah and it works for me.

Comment: In a APNS payload the `aps` key is mandatory, keys like `acme1` are optional and customizable. Your `userInfo` dictionary contains the keys `aps`, `message` and `link`. As already said in the other question, **do not** cast the type to generics like `AnyObject` or `NSObject`. The keys of a APNS payload are all `String`, the values either `String`, `Int / Double` or a collection type `Array` or `Dictionary`.

Comment: yeah got it, thank you @vadian